# Unable to find a .dll in the modules window (VS 2008 C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

This is kind of a stupid question I guess, but I have a library which is included and used in a project, compiled as a .dll. Everything compiles fine. When I reach a function in this library, I get System.AccessViolationException and I cannot enter into it while debugging because it says the symbols are not loaded.

I have looked in the modules window, and I cannot find my .dll

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a managed/unmanaged debugging issue.  You won't see unmanaged DLL's if you are doing managed debugging, and vice-versa.  The "automatic" option where VS tries to guess what kind of debugging you want doesn't always work.

Try attaching to the process after it is loaded and then specify both managed and unmanaged debugging in the dialog that pops up when you choose the Debug->Attach To Process menu option.

Comment: My project is a module for a commercial software. When I launch it in debug mode, the software.exe process is in grey, with type "Managed". And I cannot attach anything to this executable...

But I think you're certainly right about the managed/unamanged stuff.